# Is an aluminium radiant barrier allowed to cover insulation paper facing instead of drywall?

Tags: drywall, insulation, code-compliance, radiant-barrier, fire

First some context:

- Geographical location: City of Sacramento, CA, USA
- Building: Residential detached garage.
- Goal: To keep it cool in the summer and warm in the winter.
- Approach: kraft paper faced fiberglass batt insulation was stapled between the rafters. Now I thought I was finished...not:

Problem: The paper facing states (readable from within the garage):

> WARNING! This facing will burn. Do not leave exposed. It must be
>   covered with gypsum board or other code-approved materials and
>   installed in compliance with all building codes. To prevent a fire,
>   keep open flames and other sources of heat away from the facing.

The product documentation, consistently, states:

> Kraft and standard foil facing will burn. Do not leave exposed. Facing
>   must be installed in substantial contact with an approved ceiling,
>   floor or wall material.

**Question**: Is it allowed to staple an aluminium foil radiant barrier (assume fire rating Class A / Class 1, ASTM E-84) over the paper facing to meet code as shown in the figure below? It's easier to install compared to drywall.

[image: Schematic Garage roof cross-section]

Comment: What is the fire rating of the aluminum barrier? I believe it must be 15 minute or longer. A detached structure may not require the fire rating without a living space.

Comment: This [1,2] is an example foil (the manufacturer does not explicitly state a number of minutes, maybe it is implicitly given by the rating, I don't know...) Fire Rating: Class A / Class 1; Flame Spread Test: 0; Smoke Development Test: 10; (ASTM E84-10 with ASTM E2599); 
[1] https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00B1HG2NA/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza [2] https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/C1lKbf5bLbS.pdf